# Finding connection between different classes in JAR

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I'm parsing a JAR by myself (I'm not using JarFile), and then I dynamically load each class from that JAR.
The problem is that some of the classes might have dependencies on other classes from that JAR.
How do I find if there are any dependencies for each class in that JAR?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to download the source jar, parse a corresponding java file and load all classes from the `import` section at the beginning of each file.

If there's no source jar, try decompiling each class back into java file.

Comment: I'm doing this dynamically on runtime, so I can't download the source.

Comment: Are you dynamically downloading the jar with the classes? Most probably not. So, together with the classes jar, download the sources. Maven would do the job for you downloading all the transitive dependencies.